# how is it possible that an answer come before question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, questions, answers, timestamps

in some questions, like this:
[Deletion of copy-ctor & copy-assignment - public, private or protected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55205874/deletion-of-copy-ctor-copy-assignment-public-private-or-protected)
you can see that the question was asked in 2019, but somehow there is an answer in 2017. the answer which Potatoswatter answered.
how is it possible?

Comment: See the [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55205874/timeline), it was merged with another question.